# Natural parameterization of the following curves:

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, partial-fractions

I am having trouble finding the natural parameterization of these curves:

> $$\alpha(t)=\left(\sin^2\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right),\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(t\sqrt{2}\right), \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$

The thing is when finding $$\|\alpha'(t)\|=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}\sin^2\left({\sqrt{2}t}\right)+1}$$
I do not know how to integrate this.
The second one I have is

> $$\beta(t)=\left(\frac{4}{5}\cos t,1-\sin{t},-\frac{3}{5}\cos t\right)$$

I get $s=4\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right)$ or $t=2\arccos({4-s})$

I am to find the Tangent, normal, binormal, tangent and curvature of the curves, but I am at a block, because when I try to naturally parameterize then I come to problems:

1. For the first one, I cannot figure out the integral of $\|\alpha'(t)\|$
2. For the second one I think I have made a mistake because finding the derivative when putting $t$ in dependence of $s$ in $\beta(t)$ would be very messy business to find the derivative for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha(t)=\left(\sin^2\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right),\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(t\sqrt{2}\right), \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)
$

Since
$\sin^2(x)
=\frac12(1-\cos(2x))
$,
$\sin^2\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
=\frac12(1-\cos(2\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}))
=\frac12(1-\cos(t\sqrt{2}))
$,
so
$\alpha(t)
=\left(\frac12(1-\cos(t\sqrt{2}))
,\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(t\sqrt{2}\right)
, \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)
$.

From this,
$\alpha'(t)
=\left((\sqrt{2}/2)\sin(t\sqrt{2})
,(\sqrt{2}/2)\cos \left(t\sqrt{2}\right)
, \left(\sqrt{2}/2\right)\right)
=(\sqrt{2}/2)\left(\sin(t\sqrt{2})
,\cos \left(t\sqrt{2}\right)
,1\right)
$
so that
$||\alpha'(t)||^2
=(1/2)(1+1)
=1
$.

Answer (score 1):

$\beta(t)=\left(\frac{4}{5}\cos t,1-\sin{t},-\dfrac{3}{5}\cos t\right)$

$\beta'(t)=\left(-\dfrac45\sin t,-\cos t,\dfrac 35\sin t\right)$ Then,

$\Vert\beta'(t)\Vert^2=\left(\dfrac{4^2}{5^2}\sin^2t+\cos^2t+\dfrac{3^2}{5^2}\sin^2t\right)=\left(\dfrac{4^2+3^2}{5^2}\sin^2t+\cos^2t\right)=1$

So, $s=\int_{0}^t1\mathrm d\tau=t$ The curve was already parametrized by arclength.